# How to fix my external javascript file of my php file doesn't show up or load at sources?

Tags: javascript

What are possible causes of my javascript external code not showing at all at page sources when I press ctrl+shift+I?I use NetBeans as IDE.

Comment: What is `ctrl+shift+I`? How is it related to NetBeans?

Comment: Shortcut to fix all class imports.
Maybe it can't find your javascript file. Check the path